# How to debug this error from google?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services

In my android app I am receiving this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ok.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.et.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.gt.run(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.gv.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I can't determine what this is related to, so I can't find a way to fix it.

I am using "Google Play Services" for subscription purchases and "Google Admob" to service ads.  I **think** this is related to one of those items but I can't be sure.

I have run this stack trace through proguard's retrace utility in the hopes that it was obfuscated by my proguard run...but it is not.  It returns the same stack trace from the retrace.

This is getting caught in a global error handler in my application.  I take the global errors that are caught and dump them to remote database (web service).  There have been a number of these errors lately.  They started when I updated the google play services (which has both the new subscription stuff and the new admob that everyone was forced to migrate to)

Since it is on a separate thread (see bottom of stack), I could check the stack trace for "com.google.android.gms.internal" and just ignore it.   But, I really have no idea what this is coming from so I don't know if ignoring the error will have any downstream effects.

I would really like to get the bottom of the error.

Does anyone have ANY idea how this can be debugged?  How can I track down what the service is that is crashing?  Is there a forum somewhere that google devs monitor that I might be able to submit and get somewhere with this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes seems like a Google Play Services bug of some sort. You are using the very latest version? And more importantly, can you reproduce it or does it happen on some devices.

Comment: I am using the very latest version of google play.  I have never been able to reproduce it here, but it happens "live" quite a bit.  I capture phone OS information on an unhandled exception so I have the OS versions, the phone types, etc.  I don't see any pattern.  The OS versions range from 2.3.1 to 4.3.1.  The makes are all across the board (HTC, Samsung, LG, Etc.).  I'm a little baffled.